# Mute hotkey for Office Communicator 2007 R2

Tags: hotkeys, office-communicator-2007

Is there a hotkey combination for muting and unmuting your microphone in an MOC 2007 R2 conference?

Answer (score 1):

According to all the [keyboard shortcuts](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/communicator-help/office-communicator-2007-r2-keyboard-shortcuts-HA010289966.aspx) for MOC 2007 R2, the only one that comes close is:

> Place a call on hold/Resume call.  This shortcut is available from the
>   Communicator Conversation window. CTRL + SHIFT + H